# Is this a reasonable way to "namespace" globals that my javascript scripts use to prevent collisions with other scripts

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

I'm a somewhat newish javascript programmer, who is easily surprised or overwhelmed by some of the nuances of the language, although I've been a programmer for over 50 years and used lots of languages including fortran, pascal, C, C++, PL/I, assembly language, microcode, IBM MVS JCL, etc.

I saw somewhere a piece of javascript code that began something like this:

```
ModuleX = ModuleX || {};
```

and the rest of the code in various functions, sometimes in other files, proceeded to create/modify properties of this global object with impunity, "knowing" that there would not be name collisions with other javascript files that were loaded. I know there are any number of different module systems for javascript, but this simple convention struck me as crude but simple and useful, and I've used it a lot. So when I want a global function that I can call from any of my scripts, I write:

```
ModuleX.myfunc = function() {...};
```

This seemed fine until I accidentally copy-pasted some lines of code that contained such function definitions into another part of the same file, and then when I wanted to make some changes to the function, not noticing which definition I was changing! My knee-jerk reaction was "what a stupid language, that it doesn't detect duplicate global function definitions". And then I said to myself, maybe I should be writing

```
const ModuleX.myfunc = function() {};
```

But apparently that's not valid since const cannot be used at global scope.

Is this just silly, should I instead just use prefixes on names instead of an object, e.g.

```
ModuleX_myfunc() {};
```

or something else that would be similarly simple? Suggestions?